# Coconut Shrimp-fry ahead for dinner party?

Tags: food-safety, deep-frying, shrimp

I see a few opinions on my question, from a few years ago. Just wondering if anyone has an updated idea. I want to serve fresh and crunchy coconut shrimp as part of a dinner party for 12 people. I would prefer to not have the smell and time of frying, as my guests are in attendance. Can I fry two hours prior to dinner and have them sit at room temp....with a very quick flash-heat in the oven? If so, how long and at what temp (450 or so)? Wracking my brain to try and come up with the best viable option. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You will never achieve the same texture and doneness after two hours that you will when your shrimp come out of the fryer...unless, of course, you have access to a CVap oven.  The CVap was invented (I believe by Col. Saunders for Kentucky Fried Chicken) to solve the problem you identify.  Shrimp cook very quickly, but without access to a commercial deep-fryer (which I assume), cooking for 12 on your stove will be slow.  Personally, I would save something like this for a small gathering and choose a dish that I could pull off well for a larger group.